# Hashing in ms Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, hash, capicom

I'm trying to hash a password in ms access (preferably MD5 or SHA-1). I found Capicom, which worked great at school on windows XP. However, at home Access doesn't seem to want to recognize it. Is there any alternatives that I can use which will work on both XP and Windows 7 that doesn't involve adding external library?

And if an external library is required, how can I add this into the VB code for my database.
Thanks.

e: anything that needs to be installed, eg a .dll file, is out of the question as I wont be able to use it at school (My issue is finding something which will work at home and at school so I can effectively work on my project)

Comment: maybe something like this? http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=741.  Vb but should also be ok in VBA.

Comment: A search in SO on `[ms-access] MD5 SHA-1` returned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492523/calculating-md5-of-string-from-microsoft-access, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

CAPICOM redistributable; http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25281 - Note that its 32bit only

Comment: I have windows 7 64 bit, so I take it that that won't work.
e: tried it anyway but it didn't work

Comment: How are you calling this external libary?Everything you are installing with an exception of a few programs is 32 bit, and that includes Access. There is an x64 bit version of Access for office 2010, but most recommend you stick to the 32 bit. So the vast majority of software you are running is x32 despite running on an x64 os system. So x32 code systems can use and call x32 code libraries and the fact that both are running on an x64 OS does not matter. However an x32 bit version of office cannot call an x64 code library.

Comment: I do have 64 bit Access installed. Would installing the 32 bit version be compatible with CAPICOM?